# Toolbar sidemenu with title and scrollable content

Tags: codenameone, sidebar

I would like to create a sidemenu with a title and a scrollable content.
I also tried a few things:

```
  //that works: i can scroll in the content container and the status label stay on top but it's in my welcome form
    Form welcome = new Form("Welcome");
    welcome.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Label welcomeStatusLabel = new Label("STATUS");
    Container welcomeContent = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    welcomeContent.setScrollableY(true);

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        welcomeContent.add(new Label("Item "+i));

    welcome.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,welcomeStatusLabel);
    welcome.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,welcomeContent);
```

Now I want the same behaviour in my sidemenu and i try that:

```
   //that doesn't work: I can't scroll
    Form menu= new Form("Menu");
    menu.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        menu.add(new Label("Item "+i));

    welcome.getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(menu);
```

Maybe I can't put a form in my toolbar sidemenu so i try with a container:

```
     //that doesn't work: the status label will scroll with the content
    Container menuContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    menuContainer.add(BorderLayout.NORTH,new Label("MENU STATUS"));
    Container menuContent = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        menuContent.add(new Label("Item "+i));

    menuContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,menuContent);
    //if I uncomment these two lines the content won't scroll anymore on simulator. On android it scrolls with the status label
    //menuContainer.setScrollableY(false);
    //menuContent.setScrollableY(true);
    welcome.getToolbar().getMenuBar().setScrollableY(false);//I don't know what that line does
    welcome.getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(menuContainer);
```

Maybe I shouldn't do that in a sidemenu ? or maybe i don't use the right components ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards.

Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add a `Form` into another component and not into the side menu.

If you just want the side menu to look like the form title area you can do something like:

```
SpanLabel fakeTitle = new SpanLabel("My Title", "Title");
fakeTitle.setUIID("TitleArea");
welcome.getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(fakeTitle);
```

I wouldn't do that though. Check out some of [our demos](https://www.codenameone.com/demos.html) for nice side menu designs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Shai, but I need that title to stay on top of the sidemenu and i also want to add a button in order to navigate since I'll update the content of my sidebar. Maybe that's something I shoudln't do in a sidebar. I'll may have to create a new form. I've checked the demos but i couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you have a screenshot of what you are trying to accomplish I might provide a better answer.

Comment: Here is what i would like to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ooaN.png

The scrollable part is going to be updated during runtime
The static part stays on top of the screen and doesn't scroll.

Comment: Do you want the title to stay fixed in place within the side menu while the content scrolls or some other aspect of that image? If the former that's a use case we don't currently support.

Comment: Yes i wanted the title to be static. Too bad it's not supported. Thanks a lot for the time you took to answer my question. Cheers